# CSS Hovering not working correctly

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I have some issues with CSS hover, what I'm doing wrong?

I'm trying to achieve that when I hover over image, transparent div with a link in it covers it so you can click on it and go to another page.
Something resembling like on this page  http://sputniknews.com/ when hovering over news

When I hover over image ,  tag is out of   and hovering not displayed properly.
Stuck with this changed code many times, don't know what to do

```css
.cvr:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600);
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  visibility: visible;
}
.link {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.cvr:hover>.link {
  visibility: visible;
}
.img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the `:hover` pseudo-selector to the parent of the element you'd like to have appear during this state.

Currently, you have it applied to `.cvr`, you need to declare that rule on the parent containing element; which is `.person`.

```css
.cvr {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600);
    height: 100%;
    width: inherit;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    transition: .7s;
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -500px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.link {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
}
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.person:hover .cvr {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.person {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple way to achieve this.
I suggest you to use a position relative on your container and position absolute on your link container. You use rgba color to play with opacity too:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

The first three value represent the rgb color code and the last represent the opacity from 0 to 1.

I have slightly changed you're html so that you're class are more representative to their function.
Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ecpb6tre

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add this:

```
.cvr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Then, add:

```
.person {
    position: relative;
}
```

The reason this works is that absolute positioning is relative to the elements first parent that has it's position attribute explicitly declared. Since the .person class has no position declared, putting position: absolute on the child element assumes you mean to position it relative to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and it works.

```
<style>
.person { position:relative; width:50%; }
.person .cvr { display:none; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.600); height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px;  top: 0px; visibility: visible; }
.person:hover .cvr { display:block; }
.person img { width:100%; }
.person .textdiv { display:table; height: 100%; width: 100%; } 
.person .cvr a { display: table-cell; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: aliceblue; vertical-align: middle; }
</style>

<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <div class="textdiv"><a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="person">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.gene-quantification.de/logo-img-cz.png">
  <div class="cvr">
    <div class="textdiv"><a class="link" href="#"> link text is here</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```